# get specific variable from html5player external source

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh` var from an external source that renders like this:

```
<script>
    logged_user = false;
    var static_id_cdn = 2;
    var html5player = new HTML5Player('html5video', '38295'); //this is the video ID
    if (html5player) {
        html5player.setVideoTitle('video title goes here');
        html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://random-prefix-here.site-url.com/videos/mp4/random-part-of-url');

        ...
   }
</script>
```

Firstly, I do `file_get_contents` to get the embed code:

```
$videoID = 38295; 
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.site-url.com/embedframe{$videoID}');
```

then, I look for a url match that contains specific parts like (site-url.com/videos/mp4/) to eco it, like this:

```
   preg_match('/https:\/\/[^\"]*/\.site-url\.com\/videos\/mp4\/[^\"]*/', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
   $videoURL = ($matches[0][0]);
   echo '=>' . $videoURL;
```

but this is not working... Where am I failing?

Please keep in mind that both `random-prefix-here` and `random-part-of-url` should be replaced by regex in a possible solution.

**UPDATED**

I already tried this also, witouth any results:

```
$url = 'http://www.site-url.com/embedframe38295/';
$content= file_get_contents($url);
  preg_match_all('#html5player.setVideoUrlHigh\((.+?)\')', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
   $videoURL = ($matches[0][0]);
echo $videoURL;
```

Comment: Why are you making this so hard on yourself … match what is in between `html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('` and the next `');`, if the full URL is what you want as a result.

Comment: @CBroe I already tried this way `$getVideoUrlHigh = "#html5player.setVideoUrlHigh\((.+?)\);";` but I get no results...

Comment: Well with that you should only get an error message, telling you that the trailing delimiter is missing. (Didn’t get that error? Then make sure you properly configured your PHP error reporting for dev purposes!) Once you add that, it should work. (You might want to also include the `'` already outside of the grouping braces, otherwise you get `'url'` instead of just `url` out of this.)

Comment: nothing still. can you please examplify with a bit of code?

Comment: Update your question with what you tried please.

Comment: @CBroe done. Thanks!